# Configuring Java for R

Tags: java, r

I am trying to configure (Oracle) Java 10.0.1 for R 3.4.4 on MacOS 10.13.4 and I get an error.
Any hint how I can make this work?
I tried with both Xcode and the clang environment used for compiling R.

```
Mozart:~ neuwirth$ R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 10.0.1
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
In file included from conftest.c:1:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h:39:10: fatal error: 
      'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

Comment: You need to give more background information here.  It looks like you're making JNI calls from your Java code.  That by itself can be tricky in Java.

Comment: I am trying to install a packages using Java in R. And it seems the build process for this packages cannot find some things it needs.